# Obtain Averages From an Output Table

Tags: sas

With the gracious help from another another use, I created a code that sums the number of patients we have in an Emergency Room at a given hour. This code uses two variables 'checkin_date_time' and 'dispo_date_time' to determine the hours when the patient is in the Emergency Room. So, for example, and patient here from 10am to Noon was counted as in the ER for hours 10am and 11am.

To obtain the average, I could run the code for each day or simple by hand calculate the averages when running the code over a period of weeks/months; however, I was curious if there is a simpler option in SAS that would produce an outputted average.

Here is the code I'm working with

```
 data ED_TAT1;
 set ED_TAT;
 where datepart(checkin_date_time) between '01MAR2019'd and '31MAR2019'd;
 format checkin_date_time dispo_date_time datetime18.;
 run; 

 data ED_TAT2;
 set ED_TAT1;
 counttime = round(checkin_date_time,3600);
 format counttime datetime18.;
 do while (counttime le round(dispo_date_time,3600) );
  hr = timepart(counttime);
  day = weekday(datepart(counttime));
  output;
  counttime= intnx('hour',counttime,1,'B');
 end;
 run;

 proc tabulate data=ED_TAT3;
 class hr day;
 format hr timeampm5. ;
 table hr='', day*n=''/ box=hr;
 label hr='Hour'
     day= 'Day of week';
 run;
```

It produces a table that looks like this

```
 Hour    Day of Week
          1    2     3  ...
 12AM     234   423   533
 1AM      464   123   323
 2AM      123   213   324
 ...
```

I would like to produce the same table but each data cell contains averages for each hour by day of week. So for Day 1 at 12AM,  I want the cell to be 234/5(Sundays in March ) =**46.8** patients.

I attempted to use the following code to get the averages but the outputted averages are not correct-they are much lower than what the averages should be when dividing by the number of days March.

```
 proc sql;
 create table Avg as
 select hr, mean(case when day=1 then . else day end) as day1,
       mean(case when day=2 then . else day end) as day2
 from ED_TAT3
 group by hr;
 quit;
```

Comment: 1. Use PROC FREQ instead of tabulate to get the counts into a data set - google or check the docs.2. Use PROC MEANS on the FREQ output directly.

Comment: @Reeza, thanks! I'll try that option out although, I'm not sure it will work-for example there may be times where month has 4 Sundays and 5 Mondays.

Comment: The point of calculating averages is to ignore some of that. Or I'm missing something here.

Comment: Not exactly, but thank you @Reeza. As I stipulated in my question, I'm looking for the average at a specific hour per day. So if the count (n) is 400 at 11am on day 1(Sundays) and there are 4 Sundays in March. The average should be 100. Also, I am aware of proc means and freq, I just assumed these weren't viable options for my specific question. Furthermore, how can I ensure my questions don't get marked off? I feel this was a good question where I showed thought.

Answer (score 1):

PROC MEANS and FREQ are the two of the most useful PROCs in SAS, worth learning them.

```
data have;
   informat patient_id $2. checkintime releasetime datetime18.;
   format checkintime releasetime datetime18.;
   input patient_id checkintime releasetime   ;
datalines;
01 01AUG2015:02:49:00        01AUG2015:08:29:00
02 01AUG2015:01:30:00        02AUG2015:14:29:00
03 02AUG2015:21:30:00        02SEP2015:01:20:00
;
run;

data temp;
   set have;
   counttime = round(checkintime,3600);
   format counttime datetime18.;
   do while (counttime le round(releasetime,3600) );
      hr = timepart(counttime);
      day = weekday(datepart(counttime));
      date = datepart(counttime);

      output;
      counttime= intnx('hour',counttime,1,'B');
   end;
run;


proc freq data=temp;
by date;
format date yymon6.;
table hr*day / out=raw_counts;
run;

proc means data=raw_counts stackods N MEAN;
class date hr day;
var count;
ods output summary=want;
run;

proc print data=want;run;
```